# How long does it take for Portuguese consulates to process short-term visa applications?

Tags: visas, portugal

I'm going to Mauritius on 27 june and require a Portuguese visa before that. Is there any way out? I'm going to Portugal on 10 June and will be back from previous trip by 6 June. So no time left later.

Comment: Among other things, it depends on your nationality and country of residence. In any case, if you need a visa to Schengen, not very likely.

Comment: I'm confused.  If you are going to Portugal on 10 June, you have nearly three weeks, not 5 days, in which to get the visa.  What is the relevance of the trip to Mauritius, which occurs 2.5 weeks after you depart for Portugal?

Comment: I think the OP is traveling now, so can't apply for a Portuguese visa in his or her country of residence until 6 June.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Embassy of Portugal to the United States](http://www.embassyportugal-us.org/Embassy_of_Portugal/Visa_Info_for_Schengen_States.html):

> As the **processing of your application visa may take up to 1 month**, it is essential to apply with anticipation.

Other Portuguese consulates worldwide should have similar processing times.